# NoMethodError (undefined method) however class method is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a new class **Project** which is inherited from **ActiveRecord::Base**. I defined a class method called **get_all** and I would like to use in Controller but I got **NoMethodError (undefined method for ...)**

Model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.get_all
    find(:all)
  end

end
```

Controller:

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
  unloadable

  def index
    @projects = Project.get_all
  end
end
```

Comment: You could just use Project.all in your controller to get all of the projects. Can you please post the stack trace?

Comment: Which method is undefined? because get_all is clearly defined (though you do not need it actually as already said), but what is `unloadable`? Is it some inner Rails method, or your own?

Answer (score 1):

Note that in rails 3 the `find(:all)` method ( without any options ) is deprecated in favor of the `all` method. More about it:

http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

Also, I don't know why are you making that function, when you could just do:

```
@projects = Project.all
```

just like chrisbulmer said.

This should work:

## Project model

```
  def self.get_all
    Project.all
  end
```

Comment: Just an example, I would like to create complex queries throught the class methods.

Comment: okay, cool :) Did this help you? You can chain your methods on the `Project.all`

Comment: It is not working. I have changed this:

`class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

 def self.get_all
  all
 end

end`

Comment: make it `Project.all` instead of `all`

Comment: I have got the following error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `get_all' for #<Class:0x00000005467468>):
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606)

Comment: Same. I can't define instance methods or class methods in a class which is a "model" class. I don't know why

Comment: I know yet. I deleted my classes in model directory, and I can use Project in my controller, and so in my controller the "Project" isn't same the "Project" in my models. That is comprehensible. The next question is why can't I define data models?

Comment: I used this command:

`ruby script/rails generate redmine_plugin_model <plugin_name> <model_name>`